# TFS and SSIS - Automatic checkout issue

Tags: xml, tfs, ssis

Is there a way to ignore the xml changed in a dtsx file when it checks out automatically (opens, executes), even if there have not been any changes to package behaviour?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'ignore'?

Comment: Ignore means TFS will not detect a pending change and check out the SSIS file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a similar issue to this recently and I have seen it in the past when working on previous projects.

I believe that the issue stems from the fact that the .database file is not included in the source control by default and this causes the dtproj file to be amended each time it is opened.

I found a fix for it that worked in my situation and blogged it here: http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/blogs/jeoc/archive/2015/03/20/18156.aspx

To summarise the changes that you need to make (if it is caused by the same issue) you should do the following:

1. Unload the affected SSIS project(s)
2. Edit the .dtproj files to point to the correct .database file
3. Add the .database file to source control
4. Check in the changes.
5. Reload the project and ensure it doesn't automatically check-out
6. Ensure all users do a get latest on the solution.

Hopefully this helps, if not please let me know what happens and perhaps there is another solution.
Kind regards

Jon

Comment: Jon, we try to avoid answers that are just links, because the link could stop working. Could you edit your answer to include a summary of the relevant section of the linked article?

Comment: Sure, I have edited as requested to provide a summary of the fix :)